# How to boot into Ubuntu installed on disk with "partition table: loop"?

Tags: dual-boot, grub

After some changes I can't boot into my Ubuntu installed on separate disk. GRUB from other installation doesn't see it (nor `grub-repair` suggests it) and disk doesn't even appear in UEFI boot options.

I tried to reinstall GRUB into it:

```
mount /dev/sdd /mnt
grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi /dev/sdd
```

But it failed:

```
grub-install: error: /mnt/boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition.
```

After a little investigation it appeared that disk has a weird partition table (precisely, it's absence) called [`loop`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295180):

`sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA KINGSTON SA400S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 480GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  480GB  480GB  ext4
```

Is there a way to turn such disk into a regular bootable disk or maybe somehow add an option to boot from it inside GRUB menu?

How such Ubuntu could work in the first place? It was installed normally from `Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB` and was appearing properly as an option in GRUB menu. How can I avoid such `loop`s in the future?

P.S. `mount /dev/sdd /mnt && df /mnt/ && umount /mnt` output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd       460368768 250624628 186285180  58% /mnt
```

Comment: Did you copy ISO to that drive? Or install without a partition table? You normally want gpt, not old MBR(msdos) partitions. Loop is typically used to manually mount an ISO written as iso9660 or UDF and now loop is seen a lot with snaps as they are all loops.

Comment: @oldfred I don't think I did any ISO copies, no, I installed normally through GUI from Ubuntu's `Live USB` by pointing to specific drive as I was doing many times before. I thought that maybe interface somehow changed in version 22.04 and I didn't notice it, but an hour ago I installed it again on different disk and that disk now has `Partition Table: gpt`.

Comment: May you please add the output of the following commands to your original post? `mount /dev/sdd /mnt && df /mnt/ && umount /mnt`

Comment: @paladin added the info. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Your problem is solveable, please give me some time to write an answer.